# Vue Spa show <noscript> tag content as description text in search engine. ex.Google search

Tags: vue.js, frontend, seo

I have a landing page build using Vue 2 with vue router and vue pwa.

When public to production, everything run okay but when i search my web in Google, results show only **title page, content in *noscript* tag as description** and **when view cached version of my page Google show totally empty page**.

But my web on production still run normal, full function and i definitely don't disable Js in browser. I also tried use Google Search Console to request re-index my page but nothing change.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Disable prefetch and preload in vue.config.js resolved my problem.

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  config.plugins.delete('preload')
  config.plugins.delete('prefetch')
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything turned on in the server? Just had that happen today anyway what code you using to add the title and description. Looks like something may not be executing when the page loads.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: My web is basis vue and i probably dont change many config and my code seems  ok. But I worry about my page blank when i view its cached version in Google search, seem like Google bot can't crawl anything on my page